# Recursive binary search not working systematically

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, search

I am implementing the binary search algorithm with both an **iterative** and **recursive** approach.

The first line of the input contains an integer `n` and a sequence of `n` pairwise distinct positive integers in increasing order.
The next line contains an integer `k` and `k` positive integers.

For all `i` from 0 to `k - 1`, output an index `0 <= j <= n-1` such that `a_j = b_i`, or `-1` if there is no such index. (for each algorithm implementation)

a and b are respectively the elements of each sequence.

**Input:**

```
5 1 5 8 12 13
5 8 1 23 1 11
```

**Output:**

```
2 0 -1 0 -1
2 0 -1 0 -1
2 0 -1 0 -1
```

I managed to implement the iterative, recursive version and a linear search version.

```
import sys

def binary_search_it(a, x):
    left, right = 0, len(a) - 1
    while left <= right:
        mid = left + (right - left) // 2
        if x == a[mid]:
            return mid
        # left--mid--x--right
        if a[mid] < x:
            left = mid + 1
        # left--x--mid--right
        elif x < a[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
    return - 1

def binary_search_rec(a, x):
    left, right = 0, len(a) - 1
    if right < left:
        return left - 1
    mid = left + (right - left) // 2
    if x == a[mid]:
        return mid
    if x < a[mid]:
        return binary_search_rec(a[: mid - 1], x)
    else:
        return binary_search_rec(a[mid + 1:],x)


def linear_search(a, x):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == x:
            return i
    return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    data = list(map(int, input.split()))
    n = data[0]
    m = data[n + 1]
    a = data[1 : n + 1]
    for x in data[n + 2:]:
        # replace with the call to binary_search when implemented
        print(binary_search_it(a, x), end=' ')
    print('\n')
    for x in data[n + 2:]:
        print(linear_search(a, x), end=' ')
    print('\n')
    for x in data[n + 2:]:
        print(binary_search_rec(a, x), end = ' ')
```

So far everything is fine, for the example above the code return the same output for all three implementations.

If I try to use another sample dataset I have an issue in my recursive approach

Input:

```
5 1 2 3 4 5
5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Output (expected):

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 -1 2 0 0
```

Can someone explain me the flow in my code and how you manage to identify the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this implementation:

- Using slicing is expensive and makes this algorithm *O(n)*
- The recursive algorithm never ever returns `-1` to indicate that the item was not found.

A recursive implementation of binary search still needs to track `left` and `right` to be *O(log n)*.

```
def binary_search_rec(a, x):
    return _binary_search(a, x, 0, len(a) - 1)

def _binary_search(a, x, left, right):
    if right < left:
        return -1

    mid = (right + left) // 2
    if x == a[mid]:
        return mid
    if x < a[mid]:
        return _binary_search(a, x, left, right - 1)
    else:
        return _binary_search(a, x, left + 1, right)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
...
if x < a[mid]:
    return binary_search_rec(a[: mid - 1], x)  <---
...
```

The upperbound on a slice is **exclusive**. See for e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) for more details.

How to find such problems? Either by knowing the algorithm and the language well enough to identify mistakes in the code by reading it, or via a debugger. A debugger should come with every IDE available for python, or standalone. Learning to use one should be one of the top-priorities of any beginning coder.